# Change "et al" for "y col." in natbib

Tags: natbib, naming

I'm using `natbib` to make the citations in my document. When I cite an article that has more than one author with  `\citep{Ak-Suleimani1999}`, I have, in the output:

> Ak-Suleimani et al., 1999

The problem is that I would like to have:

> Ak-Suleimani y col., 1999

I had read that, with `biblatex`, it is a really easy thing to do:

[Replace `et al.` with `\& al.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/replace-et-al-with-al)

But I didn't find a way to do this with `natbib`. I really would like to keep working with this package, so I don't have to change a lot of code trough my almost ready document.

Comment: It is buried as a fixed string `et~al.` in the bibliography style file, e.g. `plainnat.bst`.  You could make a local copy, with a new name, and replace that one occurance.

Comment: Lev Bishop's answer to the linked question deals with `natbib`/ BibTeX.

Comment: Saw that, but I think that's not a great way to fix it. I was looking something more like `\usepackage[someoption]{natbib}` so I don't have to change the .bst file every time I compile.

Comment: @user215982 Regrettably, the appearance of `et al.` is (usually) hard-coded into `.bst` styles when using `natbib`. There is no 'magic' fix for this, so I'd say the linked question is the best you'll find.